# Deleted question. How to recover some information?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions

Not so long ago I have posted an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881584/why-does-every-maximal-ideal-closed-in-mathfraka-topology-imply-that-math/881619#881619), and the OP deleted it immediately after.

I don't want to comment on this behavior, instead I'd like to repost it for the benefit of other readers of M.SE. (I know that users rated >10k can see such questions, but I think it would be nice to have a rating-free feature to help us in such cases.)

Comment: Immediately here is about 12 hours. Just to put a timeframe to those that can't see the question.

Comment: You wrote that the question was immediately deleted. Here, in your question, immediately means almost 12 hours.

Comment: It seems that Google still has a cached version - [link to search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Why+does+every+maximal+ideal+closed+in+a-topology+imply+that+a%E2%8A%86Jac%28A%29%3F%22). Will this be sufficient for you or should I (or someone else) copy the text of the question here (or somewhere)?

Comment: BTW I think this should be tagged ([meta-tag:specific-question]).

Comment: Maybe I'm writing this from my phone and can't quite help you with that.

Comment: @Martin: Maybe it should be just undeleted?

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok, I have voted to undelete. Two more votes needed. At the same time I have copied all the relevant information to an answer.

Comment: @Martin: One more.

Comment: Undeleted. ${}$

Comment: Thanks Asaf, Martin, and Gerry!

Comment: Some suggestions in the comments here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8852/27978

Comment: @ZhenLin Are you sure the OP and that BenjaLim (who actually changed his username long time before deletion) are one and the same user? Furthermore, the question here is about a deleted question, not about a deleted account.

Comment: It seems like a remarkable coincidence otherwise! (Yes, I only just remembered that he changed his username before that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have copied all the relevant information here. If this was not correct thing to do, I can simply delete this answer.

---

Question: Why does every maximal ideal closed in $\mathfrak{a}$-topology imply that $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \text{Jac}(A)$?

tagged: [commutative-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-algebra)

I must be missing something very simple, but suppose that every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of a Noetherian ring is closed in the $\mathfrak{a}$-topology on $A$. Then why does this imply that $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \text{Jac}(A)$, the Jacobson radical of $A$? I know if there is an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ not contained in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ then for every $i > 0$ we have
$$ \mathfrak{m} + \mathfrak{a}^i = A.$$

How does this contradict $\mathfrak{m}$ being closed? I can't see  the existence of $x \notin \mathfrak{m}$ with no open neighborhood about it.

---

Answer: An ideal $m$ is closed in the $a$-adic topology iff $m=\cap_{i\ge 1} (m+a^i)$. As you observed, this shows that $m+a^i\ne A$ for any $i\ge 1$. If $m$ is maximal this means that $a\subseteq m$.